# Setting a TextView width in java

Tags: java, android, textview

How can I set the TextView properties like width, height using Java Code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the activity where you inflate the view, you can grab the `TextView` with

```
TextView t = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.myTextView);
```

where `myTextView` is the `id` that you declared in your XML.

Now go ahead and `t.setText("Something");`, `t.setWidth(200)`, ...

Comment: Well I think the key to the question was the `findViewById` part, which is of course well-known to Android developers, but I guess the OP just got started in Android

Answer (score 2):

Here you have all `TextView` methods:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html

If you read the complete page, then you will become a `TextView` guru.

Comment: txtname is TextView name and 100 pixel is width.